# Why my struct has an incomplete definition?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, declaration

I am implementing a `struct` in C:

```
typedef struct {
...   
} _p_TSResilOnline;

typedef struct _p_TSResilOnline *TSResilOnline;
```

After (in the same file), I am using:

```
TSResilOnline         o  = (TSResilOnline)(chk->data);
...
*check = (o->threshold < PetscAbs(sf)) ? PETSC_FALSE : PETSC_TRUE;
```

But my compiler returns:

> error: incomplete definition of type 'struct _p_TSResilOnline'
>   *check = (o->threshold < PetscAbs(sf)) ? PETSC_FALSE : PETSC_TRUE;
>               ~^ 
>   note: forward declaration of 'struct _p_TSResilOnline' typedef struct
>   _p_TSResilOnline *TSResilOnline;

I am wondering what is incomplete. The compiler should know everything.

Comment: Because you're using an instance of the struct in the `typedef`, not the  type of the struct. Try `struct _p_TSResilOnline { ...};`

Comment: `struct { ... } _p_TSResilOnline` defines a variable of an unnamed (untagged) struct type. Add a tag to the struct definition.

Comment: Don't `typedef` a pointer! This will eventually result in confusion and flaws.

Comment: Right. So it works with: `struct _p_TSResilOnline{ ... } ;
typedef struct _p_TSResilOnline *TSResilOnline;`

Comment: Note: even when you fix the error, the code probably still violates the *strict aliasing rule*, causing undefined behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this declaration

```
struct {
...   
} _p_TSResilOnline;
```

you defined an object with identifier `_p_TSResilOnline` that has type of an unnamed structure.

In this declaration

```
typedef struct _p_TSResilOnline *TSResilOnline;
```

you declared structure type `struct _p_TSResilOnline`.

The identifier `_p_TSResilOnline` of the object and identifier `_p_TSResilOnline` used to name the structure in the typedef declaration are in different namespaces and identifies different entities.

The definition of `struct _p_TSResilOnline` is incomplete because members of the structure are unknown.

However in this expression

```
o->threshold
```

you are trying to access member with name `threshold` that was not declared.

So the compiler issues an error.

**EDIT**: After you changed the first declaration in your question the following way

```
typedef struct {
...   
} _p_TSResilOnline;
```

nevertheless again `_p_TSResilOnline` and `struct _p_TSResilOnline` are different entities and their identifiers belong to different name spaces.

You should write instead

```
struct _p_TSResilOnline {
...   
};
```

or

```
typedef struct _p_TSResilOnline {
...   
} _p_TSResilOnline;
```